# Google Calendar RateLimitExceeded Error

Tags: c#, api, calendar, limit, rate

I've been having an issue with Google Calendar API.

I can make 1 million queries per day, and 25000 queries per 100 seconds per user.
I have a task (written in C#) that make queries for each user that decided to grant the application to make a synchronization with Google Calendar and my software.
I do not exceed this **rate limit**, but for a specific user I get this message:

**Error message:**

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Rate Limit Exceeded [403] Errors [ Message[Rate Limit Exceeded] Location[ - ] Reason[rateLimitExceeded] Domain[usageLimits] ]

**Stack Trace:**

```
Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Someone can explain to me why this happens and how can I resolve it?

Edit: 
Here's my C# code

```
 //for each user
  foreach (var utente in clientContext.TbUtentiDatiDescrittivi)
  {
            var fileDataStore = GetFileDataStore();

            //get token from path
            var token = fileDataStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(utente.userID).Result;

            var credential = new UserCredential(GetCodeFlow(fileDataStore), userID, token);

            //check if token is expired, in case I update it
            if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
            {
                if (!credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                    //error, delete file
                    credential.Flow.DeleteTokenAsync(userID, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                }
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()  
            {
                   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                   ApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME,
            });

          //get request
          EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
           //...

             //get list of events
             var lstAttivitaCalendar = request.Execute().Items.ToList();//here I get the error


           //then I make some queries like
           service.Events.Delete("primary", attivita.CalendarGoogleID).Execute();
           //or
            service.Events.Update(attivitaCalendar, "primary", attivitaCalendar.Id).Execute();
}
```

Comment: Please add your C# code to the question so we can help you.

Comment: I've written the main part of my code.